# Looping with the ng-repeat Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am newbie in angular trying to loop through an array. I am not getting an error when i run the code below but I am not getting any output from the array/property customers.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4 margin-top-30">
<div class="container"  data-ng-controller="VideoController">

 <input type="text" ng-model="name" /> {{ name }}

<h3>Looping with the ng-repeat Directive</h3>
<ul>
<li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name | orderBy:city">{{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }}</li>
</ul>
</div>

<script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>

<script>
function VideoController($scope) {
    $scope.customers= [
    {name:'John Smith', city:'Phoenix'},
    {name:'John Doe', city:'San Fransisco'},
    {name:'Test Doe', city:'CPT'}
];
}
</script>


</div>
```

Can someone please point were im going wrong in the code

Comment: Which angular version are you using ?

Comment: Works here with 1.4.8 - http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1430/

Comment: Unless maybe you didn't register your controller like I did in the last line there.

Comment: I think your missing a view model in your app

Comment: and also i not see ng-app in any element

Comment: @AlonEitan, here used scope

Comment: @Grundy - Sorry, I meant angular module (`angular.module('myApp, [])...`)

Comment: @OmriAharon is right. Looks like the issue is that you are not registering your controller. You can not just define it as a function. Are you sure you aren't getting any errors in the console? If this is all your code, you should get errors about VideoController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't already have one, add an Angular app to your code:

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])`

Which you need to use in your HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

Now, anything inside that div (you can place it on other elements such as the body) will be in the scope of your app. If you want to use a controller, you have to register that to the app if you're using a version of angular that is >= 1.3:

```
myApp.controller('VideoController', VideoController);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/1430/)